# elements not lining up with float: left;

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having trouble lining up the elements in my div containing the text input boxes.

This is what it's supposed to look like:
[image]

and this is the hot mess it is right now: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bqMCP/2/

I tried

```
clear: none;
float: left;
```

in my classes, but it doesn't seem to be working out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `div` tag for **each** `text input box` and than you can decide to  `float: left;`
or `float: right;` accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `P` and a `BR`, use a `LABEL {display:block;float:left;width:80px}`.

See: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms

Comment: Definitely going to check that out. Thank you!